# Div with image over another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I want to show an image over a menu in the right, but it doesn't work on IE and Microsoft Edge on Windows 10.

```
<div class="menuDiv">
        <ul id="menu">
            <div class="menu_image"></div>
            <li><a><img src="img/image_1.png"></a>
                <ul id="seccion_1"></ul>
            </li>
            <li><a><img src="img/report_image.png"></a>
                <ul id="seccion_2"></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

menuDiv uses menu of themeRoller of jqueryUI

```
.menu_image
{
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
        content: url(../../../../../lib/img/image_logo.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*        background-position: 98% 0%;*/
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
}
```

This is how it looks on Chrome and Firefox

[image]

This is how is looks on IE

[image]

How can I show the image on IE?

I set a similar example on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/kzxfu7j4/

Comment: Which version of IE you are using currently??

Comment: Do you have a fiddle we can look at? Do the images show up but just underneath the other div? If that's the case, try looking at `z-index`

Comment: not work, the problem seems to be content: url that not show the image, I set a copy of the div <div class="menu_image"></div> apart and not show the image

Answer (score 0):

add

```
.menu{
   display: relative;
}
```

to your css or change your .menu_image as below:

```
.menu_image
{
        content: url(../../../../../lib/img/image_logo.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*        background-position: 98% 0%;*/
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        float:right;
}
```

**Edit:**
By the way make sure that the div has proper height and width, you can simply change its height and width to match the image height and width.

Comment: not work, the problem seems to be content: url that not show the image, I set a copy of the div <div class="menu_image"></div> apart and not show the image

Comment: well why don't you use `background-image` property or just putting an `img` tag in your div

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
.menu_image
{
        position: absolute; z-index: 9999;   
        content: url(../../../../../lib/img/image_logo.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        float:right;
}
```

If that not work, maybe it's the 'content' that the problem

Comment: not work, the problem seems to be content: url that not show the image, I set a copy of the div <div class="menu_image"></div> apart and not show the image

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I just set ":before" on the class menu_image and works

```
.menu_image:before
{
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
        content: url(../../../../../lib/img/image_logo.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*        background-position: 98% 0%;*/
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good answer, you should not just use psudo-elements in order to hack a CSS rule into working. It's better to use them for what they're intended. Check out my answer for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your `content` CSS attribute. This is only valid when applied to `::before` or `::after` psudo-elements:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content

You have two options:

**1)** If the image is important in the context of the content (so you definitely want all users to see it) simply add an `<img>` in the markup.

Also, since you're positioning the images with absolute positioning, it makes more sense to me to add the actual `<img>` tag and position them directly as opposed to positioning empty `div` elements and setting the image as a background.

**If the images represent navigational buttons, use this method 1.**

**2)** If the image is not important to the content context, you can add it as a background image the conventional way, using:

`background-image:url(...);`

https://jsfiddle.net/rwhxpmfm/

Background images have accessibility issues (for example, they're not included when a webpage is printed on paper and screen readers can't access them...but screen readers can access an `<img>` element's `alt` attribute) so only use them if it's just for decoration and not part of the content's context.